# \foreach iterates through list as one argument? - Help please

Tags: lists, punctuation, foreach

My question is very simple. The following lines

```
\documentclass[10pt,german]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor} %foreach 

\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA1\endcsname{1200,2800} 
\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA2\endcsname{5000,5500} 
\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA3\endcsname{1200,2800}  



\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{


\foreach \x in {#1}{
    \foreach \y in {\csname BLABLA\x\endcsname}{
    \y

    }
}


}
\begin{document}


\somecommand{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
1200,2800
5000,5500
1200,2800
```

instead of

```
1200
2800
5000
5500
1200
2800
```

`\foreach \x` iterates through `{1,2,3}` one by one.  But
`\foreach \y` iterates through `{1200,2800}` as one argument.

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to the site TeX.SE. :-) I hope that you can appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,german]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor} %foreach 

\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA1\endcsname{1200,2800}
\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA2\endcsname{5000,5500} 
\expandafter\xdef\csname BLABLA3\endcsname{1200,2800}  



\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{


\foreach \x in {#1}{\edef\mylist{\csname BLABLA\x\endcsname}
    \foreach \y in \mylist{
    \y

    }
}


}
\begin{document}


\somecommand{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: incredible! I searched for hours. Thank u very much!